# Prove that $2^n$ is $\Omega(2^{n/2})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

To prove growth rate that $2^n$ is $\Omega(2^{n/2})$ or $O(2^{n/2})$, I can take limit:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{f(n)=2^n}{g(n)=2^{\frac{n}{2}}})\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{1}{2^{-n} \times 2^{\frac{n}{2}}})\\
= \lim_{n\to \infty} (2^{\frac{n}{2}}) = \infty
\end{align*}

Meaning that $f(n) \ge g(n)$ or $f(n) \in \Omega({2^{n/2}})$, using **transpose property**:

$$f(n) \in \Omega({g(n)}) \iff g(n) \in O({f(n)})$$

We can show that  $2^n \ne O(2^{n/2})$.

**Question**: why $2^n \ne \Theta(2^{n/2})$? Is it because upper bound does not exist please, where $\Theta$ is defined as $2^n = \Theta(2^{n/2}) \iff c_1 2^{n/2} \le2^n \le c_2 2^{n/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c_1 2^{n/2} \le2^n \le c_2 2^{n/2}$ is equivalent to $c_1 \le2^{n/2} \le c_2$. But $2^{n/2}$ is not bounded from above.

Comment: Thank you. You mean $2^n$ is not bounded from above please with respect to $2^{n/2}$?

Comment: No, I mean $2^{n/2}$ is not bounded from above. $2^{n/2} \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$. That contradicts $2^{n/2} \le c_2$.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not see your multiplying $g(n)$ with constants $c_1, c_2$ in $c_1 \le2^{n/2} \le c_2$, could you please explain why? I understand the concept of $2^{n/2} \to \infty$ though.

Comment: From your post: $2^n = \Theta(2^{n/2}) \iff c_1 2^{n/2} \le2^n \le c_2 2^{n/2}$. And as I wrote $c_1 2^{n/2} \le2^n \le c_2 2^{n/2}$ is equivalent to $c_1\le2^{n/2} \le c_2$ (just divide by $2^{n/2}$).

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I got it!